# Set JavaScript object property with a function

Tags: javascript, function, object

I'm trying to set the property of an object with a function but instead, I get a value of 100 and the slide bar stuck in the middle. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
term: {
        min: 1,
        max: function(){
          var period = document.getElementById("duration").value;
          if (this.period == "days"){
            var value = 31;
          } else if(this.period == "months"){
            value = 12;
          } else {
            value = 365;
          };
          return value;
        },

        step: 1,
        _value: 10,
        get value() {
          return parseFloat(this._value);
        },
        set value(val) {
          this._value = val;
        },
        reset: function() {
          this._value = 12;
        }
      },
```

And this is the result on th UI:

[image]

EDIT:

This is how I use min and max:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.controller-row')
    .forEach(function(group) {
      var min = inputValues[group.id].min;
      var max = inputValues[group.id].max;
      var value = inputValues[group.id].value;
      var step = inputValues[group.id].step;

      var boundary = max ? 100 * (value - min) / (max - min) : 0;

      var range = group.querySelector('input[type=range]');

      range.setAttribute('style',
        'background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #4098FF 0%, #4098FF ' + boundary + '%, white ' + boundary + '%);'
      );
      range.min = min;
      range.max = max;
      range.value = value;
      range.step = step;

      var textInput = group.querySelector('input[type=number]');
      textInput.min = min;
      textInput.max = max;
      textInput.value = value;
      textInput.step = step;
    });
```

Comment: What property are you trying to set, with which function? How are you calling that function? And what does your object have to do with the UI result?

Comment: `this.period` seems to be missing

Comment: I'm trying to set the property 'max' of the object 'term' with an anonymous function (the one that follows 'max:').

Comment: But `max` is a method, not a property. You don't set it to the number `value`, you set it to the function object. Did you want to use a getter maybe? Please show the code that will use `term.max`.

Comment: OK, maybe I don't express myself correctly. What I want is to get the value of max from a function. For example, min is 1 but max varies based on the user input. If user selects 'days' max = 31, if 'months' max = 12 and if 'years' max = 100.

Comment: I've added the rest of the code in the question.

Comment: So `inputValues[group.id]` is the `term` object you defined above? Then you will have to *call* the function: `var max = inputValues[group.id].max();`!

Comment: Then I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: inputValues[group.id].max is not a function

Comment: So `inputValues[group.id]` is **not** the `term` object you defined above? Please show the code that creates `inputValues` and how it is linked to the definition of your `max` function